# jquery.ajax post request missing content-type in IE9, works in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, post, content-type

I'm trying to perform the following jQuery.ajax request and I'm facing a weird problem.

When I'm sending this request using IE9 the contentType parameter is missing although I sent it, on chrome the request is ok.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",        
        url: this.AgentServiceUrl + "/" + methodName,
        data: data,
        async: true,
        success: function (xml, textStatus) { if (successHandler != null) successHandler(xml, textStatus); },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { if (errorHandler != null) errorHandler(state, xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown); }
    });
```

I'm using jQuery 2.0.2 and jQuery.XDomainRequest.js to work with cross domain requests.

What can I do??

Answer (score 3):

$.ajax uses XDomainRequest in order to allow AJAX applications to make safe cross-origin requests

> In Internet Explorer 8, the XDomainRequest object was introduced. This
>   object allows AJAX applications to make safe cross-origin requests
>   directly by ensuring that HTTP Responses can only be read by the
>   current page if the data source indicates that the response is public

but unfortunately only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header

> In the original incarnation of the XDomainRequest object, we allowed
>   specification of the Content-Type for a POST request. It was pointed
>   out that this violated our goal of emitting only requests that HTML
>   Forms can issue, because HTML Forms are limited to sending data in
>   three different content types: text/plain,
>   application/x-www-urlencoded, and multipart/form-data. In particular,
>   it was pointed out that some AJAX server libraries would blindly
>   assume that if they received a request with a SOAP or JSON
>   Content-Type, then the client must either be trusted or Same Origin
>   (because HTML itself previously offered no way to issue cross-origin
>   requests with that Content-Type).
>
> Unfortunately, when we fixed this problem in a later IE8 Beta, we went
>   a bit too far; we restricted the content type to text/plain but didn’t
>   allow the caller to specify that the data was in
>   application/x-www-urlencoded form. This is problematic because
>   server-side frameworks (e.g. ASP, ASPNET, etc) will only automatically
>   parse a request’s fields into name-value pairs if the x-www-urlencoded
>   content type is specified.
>
> To workaround this issue, server code that currently processes HTML
>   Forms must be rewritten to manually parse the request body into
>   name-value pairs when receiving requests from XDomainRequest objects.
>   This makes adding support for the XDomainRequest object more difficult
>   than it would be otherwise.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)